# Monitoring for fragment changes in window.location URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I have two working code to do somthing if the URL has something

The first :

```
var oldLocation = location.href;
     function() {
          if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#3') > -1 ) {
               $(document).ready(function(){
                  // Do somthing
               oldLocation = location.href
          }
      });
```

It permites to launch my animation if I am on the right slide of my full background slider. Problem : works if I refresh this slide, but not if I access to slide 3 with the "Next Slide" button on my slide 2

The second :

```
var oldLocation = location.href;
 setInterval(function() {
      if(location.href != oldLocation) {
           do your action
           oldLocation = location.href
      }
  }, 1000); // check every second
```

Problem : Works but restart my animation every second

So is there a solution to mix both of them

I just want my jQuery animation to be launched if i'm on the slide 3 wherever I come from.

I hope to be understand

Thank you VERY MUCH <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTML `hashchange` event to listen changes in URL, so you don't need to manually poll it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange

Comment: Works very great exept for one detail ! How can I say to not make the animation if it has already been played. I go to the right slide my animation play, I go to the next ten come back on the right slide, the animtion replay and I don't want to. Do you have an idea ? Than you !

Comment: Store animation played state as a boolean var in window.localStorage